# Hiding a table element that has no class or id

Tags: html, css, html-table, hide

I have a table element generated by a webpage, I need to set the display to none. However, the table element doesn't have an id or a class associated with it. This is what I am left with:

```
<table role="presentation" data-name="personal">
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can hide this? I have Tried over the last week but it is out of my skillset.

I should also add that I have several other tables on the page. The only distinguishable characteristics are the 'data-name="personal"' seem to be different, therefore I could possibly target the data-name, but unsure how to do achieve this.

Comment: Is there any other table on the page? if not just hide every table?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
table[data-name="personal"] {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I'll be using this to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [CSS Attribute Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) for more details.

Your case relating to **[attribute="value"]** Selector, so you can do the following:

Using **data-name** attribute:

```css
table[data-name="personal"] {
 display:none;
}
```

Or using **role** attribute:

```css
table[role="presentation"] {
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown; is it possible to hide/show this using JavaScript. I have never used the attribute selector; therefore wondering how to achieve this using JS or jquery.

Comment: Feel free to ask anytime, Yes you can use attribute selector with jQuery, Please check this example https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_hrefattrblank

Answer (score 0):

Below are some examples you can try.Replace the 
    Attribute exists with display: none;

```
[data-value] {
/* Attribute exists */
}

[data-value="foo"] {
/* Attribute has this exact value */
}

[data-value*="foo"] {
/* Attribute value contains this value somewhere in it */
}

[data-value~="foo"] {
/* Attribute has this value in a space-separated list somewhere */
}

[data-value^="foo"] {
/* Attribute value starts with this */
}

[data-value|="foo"] {
 /* Attribute value starts with this in a dash-separated list */
}

[data-value$="foo"] {
/* Attribute value ends with this */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the details, I've used what Ehsan has sent.